# Req.body is empty using my own fetch, but works with postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I looked some similar questions but mine seems to be different, because it works with postman but it doesn't work with my own fetch - so there's nothing wrong in my backend I think.

This is my frontend:

```
url = "http://localhost:8081/signup";
op = {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: 'same-origin', 
    mode: 'cors',
    headers:{
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept':'application/json'
    },
    body:JSON.stringify({
        user:'myUser',
        password:'myPassword123',
        email:'myemail@hotmail.com'
    }),
};

fetch(url,op)
.then(dados=>dados.json())
.then(dados=>console.log(dados))
```

You see? I was careful to use x-www-form-urlencoded because i'm using a middleware in nodejs that works with urlencoded:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

In my fetch request, I was also careful to use what I just learned and I hope I learned right:

credentials: same-origin - because it is running in my localhost, so it's from the same origin and also I want to be able to get the cookies. If it belonged in another origin and I also wanted the cookies I would use include.

Mode: cors - I thought I should use this just to get data from other origin, but since didn't work with no-cors (returned lots of weird things) i'm using cors.

Here goes My code (the part that matters), but I don't think it's my backend because it worked with postman:

```
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();

    bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    const cors = require("cors");
    app.use(cors())

app.post("/signup",function(req,res){

    if(!req.body.email || !req.body.user|| !req.body.password){
        const resultado = {
            Empty: "Yes",
            Email: req.body.email,
            User: req.body.user,
            Password: req.body.password,
        }
        res.json(resultado)
        exit()
    }

    tabelaUsuario.create({
        user: req.body.user,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    }).then(()=>{
        req.session.email = req.body.email;
        res.json(req.body)
    }).catch((erro)=>{
        res.send("ERRO! erro: "+erro);
    })
})


app.listen(8081);
```

Comment: You were careful to set the header to form encoded but serialised the _actual data_ as JSON...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> bodyParser = require("body-parser");
> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
> app.use(bodyParser.json());
> ```

You have body parsing middleware for both JSON and  URL encoded bodies.

(Note that `body-parser` is a dependency of Express and is exposed through the Express API. You don't need to require it explicitly.)

---

> ```
> headers:{
>     'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
> ```

In your request you tell the server you are sending URL encoded data.

This will trigger the URL encoded body parsing middleware.

---

> ```
> body:JSON.stringify({
>     user:'myUser',
> ```

Then you send JSON.

This isn't URL encoded, so the URL encoded body parsing middleware can't parse it.

---

You need:

- To post data encoded in some format
- To have a `content-type` request header that matches that format
- To have a body parsing middleware which supports that format

You failed at the middle part.

You need to either:

- Send URL encoded data **or**
- Change the content type to say you are sending JSON encoded data